# Cloned windows to SSD, but not in boot sequence and no OS found

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, sata

Machine is a Dell Optiplex 380 (refurbished) with Windows 10 preinstalled.

I installed a Drevo SSD and since I moved the DVD sata cable from it's slot in the motherboard and connected the SSD there instead, the drive appears in the the BIOS under 'Drives'. However, it does not appear in the Boot Sequence options, and if I disconnect the HDD (which still has windows on it too), or if I insert the SSD sata cable into the primary SATA port on the motherboard, I get an operating system not found error.

I used EasUS Todo Backup to clone windows to the SSD - following [these instructions](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/migrate-windows-10-to-ssd.html). The reason I did this was because I do not have a Windows CD to do a fresh install, though I do have the product code.

This is my Disk Management setup:
[image]

F Drive is the SSD.

Originally I was getting a disk not found error, until I used the SATA port the DVD drive was using for the SSD.

I've used EaseUs Partition Master to check the drive for errors, none returned. I've also tried disabled 'Fast Boot' in BIOS, plus checked drivers are up to date for the SSD.

Comment: You must plug the SSD into the SATA port your HDD used to be on. I know you may have done this and it didn't work, but Windows is very picky. Is this EFI?

Comment: @MarkYisri No, an Optiplex 380 is old and has BIOS.

Comment: You can’t just clone the C: drive. You have to include the “System” partition. I don’t see that on “disk 1” and that is why it doesn’t work. Windows expects its partition to be #2 not #1, just like on the original drive. I also question how you cloned a partition that is significantly larger to a smaller drive.

Comment: @Appleoddity the C: drive above has a remaining capacity of 286gb - that's not the current size, hence it cloned fine. So is the solution to create a partition on the F drive and then clone the system partition from C drive to that new partition?

Comment: 286Gb is NOT the remaining capacity. It is the size of the partition. Your image doesn’t show how much of that is used. When the drive was cloned it must have resized the partition for you. The solution is to re-clone the drive including the system partition at the beginning.

Comment: @Appleoddity i see - I'm not at the machine right now but the entire contents of C drive was way under the 120gb SSD available size. It was about 30gb from memory. OK, re-clone including system, will give that a go. Not sure 'EaseUS Todo Backup' had an option to do that but if not I'm sure there's a tool that can

Comment: It should do it for you. Typically a clone would include all partitions. So, there must be an option to choose, somewhere.

Comment: you know what @Appleoddity , I reckon I specially chose the windows partition and not the whole drive probably - I looked at their docs again and it's a 'Drive/partition' clone, so I think you are right. Thanks for the help with this. If you want to put this in an answer I'd happily mark it as correct